# Forward Outlook Web Access (OWA) to GMail using POP and SMTP

Tags: microsoft-outlook, gmail, smtp, pop3

I want to receive all my company email messages in my Gmail account. Therefore I need to configure POP/SMTP access to my OWA account.

Problem is that I can't find the right POP3 server address to start the journey.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's also possible your admin has disabled pop/smtp access.  I know my military account is like that.

Answer (score 4):

In Outlook Web Access:

1. Go to *Options* in the top-right corner,
2. Choose *See all options*.
3. On the *Account* tab,
4. Click the link *Settings for POP, IMAP, and SMTP access*.

A window will pop up with the relevant settings, and information on whether the services have been disabled.

[image: Example window]

Answer (score 2):

Usually the OWA server is also your pop server, at least in small to medium installations.

Comment: You mean my OWA url?

Comment: your server's url usually isn't the OWA.  Log into OWA. Under options, there is a link to your server's POP/IMAP settings.

Comment: The POP server is usually only determined by host and port, and not by an URL. But the hostname of the URL should also be your POP host.

Answer (score 1):

It's not very elegant, but OWA does have a "forward" option/rule.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a server and install in a WebDav program which serves as a gateway with your Outlook Web Access. After that you could access your server like any other IMAP email server.

It requires the server to be turned on permanently but there are plenty of cheap cloud computer services.